# Determine if a numerical value is within some margin of a non-specific integer

Tags: javascript, math, floating-point

I am using various JavaScript `Math` functions and, due to floating point numbers, these functions occasionally return values that are either 0.000000001 larger or smaller than the correct integer answer. I am looking to set up an `if-else` statement for said functions that will return the correct integer answer should the value be within some small range of an integer (note that the non-specificity of said integer is of utmost importance).

So I am asking, is there a way, using JavaScript, to determine if the value returned from a math function (`Math.cbrt()` for example) is within some margin of a non-specific integer?

NOTE: I have tried using Number.EPSILON in a function which calculates the x-th root of a number like so

```
    var index = $('#Index').val();
    var radicand = $('#Radicand').val();
    var powerXroot = Math.pow(radicand,(1/index))+(Number.EPSILON * Math.pow(radicand,(1/index)));
```

but it doesn't work for all indicies.

Comment: lookup on stack overflow 'float comparison' or 'epsilon'

Comment: I've used Epsilon, but it still only works for some numbers.

Comment: then your code is incorrect. I suggest you show it......

Comment: Can describe _"is within some margin of a non-specific integer?"_ ? _"these functions occasionally return values that are either 0.000000001 larger or smaller than the correct integer answer"_  Can create stacksnippets to demonstrate ?

Comment: @MitchWheat See edit.

Comment: Abs() ..............................

Comment: Sorry, Mitch, maybe I'm missing something as a newbie, but how would absolute value help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Math.round()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round) to get the nearest integer to the result. If this integer is within  0.000000001 of the result, replace the result with the integer instead.

Say, you have computed `var x = ...` and want to make it an integer if it's sufficiently close to one.

```
function roundIfAlmostInteger(x) {
  if (Math.abs(x - Math.round(x)) < 0.000000001) {
    x = Math.round(x);
  }
  return x;
}
```

Illustration:

```
x = 2.3 - 0.1 - 0.2;   // now x is 1.9999999999999998
x = roundIfAlmostInteger(x);          // now x is 2
```

Comment: What do you expect to happen with cosine of 2rad? It's -0.416, nowhere near an integer.  As written in my post, you could use `roundIfAlmostInteger(Math.cos(x))`. It will not return cosine unchanged most of the time, since it's not near an integer. Also, I think I answered your question as it was stated, so I'm out.